# Error loading rewarded video ad with different errors for each device

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, ads

I am trying to show rewarded video ads in my app and every time i try and load the ad, it goes straight to the "failed to load ad" method.

For my phone i get the error:

```
W/Ads: Fail to instantiate adapter com.google.ads.mediation.chartboost.ChartboostAdapter
       android.os.RemoteException
           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzgy.zzbx(Unknown Source)
           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzgy.zzbw(Unknown Source)
           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzgy.zzbu(Unknown Source)
           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzgz$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:94)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.c.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:220)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.j.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1140)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:19)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.y.call(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1055)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.z.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:75)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

For the emulator I am using, I get the error:

```
There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
```

Also, I am assuming that the problem is not with admob as I have implemented banner ads with no problem. I am using chartboost as a meditaion.

```
import com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;
import com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost;
import com.chartboost.sdk.CBLocation;
import com.chartboost.sdk.ChartboostDelegate;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, RewardedVideoAdListener {

    SharedPreferences data;
    final String filename = "Data";

    Button btnAds;
    Button btnResetData;
    Button btnHelp;
    long adtime;

    private RewardedVideoAd mAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Chartboost.startWithAppId(this, "I have insterted my app id here", "and my app signature here");
        Chartboost.onCreate(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        btnAds = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAds);
        btnResetData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResetData);
        btnHelp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHelp);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        btnAds.setText("Loading ad...");

        // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                 .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }
    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
            mAd.loadAd("I have inserted my app unit id here", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

I've also got the other "after reward" methods and "on back" methods after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you are trying to initialize the Chartboost SDK alongside the AdMob mediation. This has been proven to be quite problematic in my own projects as the SDK and the SDK adapter do not play nice with each other.

You need to only use the AdMob methods to call Chartboost, trying to initialize separately will cause the Chartboost adapter to fail.

This IS a bit annoying given that AdMob only inits ad network SDKs as it calls them (which makes downloading assets an annoyance) but this is how AdMob is designed.

Omitting the Chartboost startwith methods and replacing them with the normal AdMob method to initialize the AdMob SDK should solve this issue.

Comment: Is that just using the MobileAds methods? I'm not sure how to initialize the AdMob SDK as I can't find anything onlline. Sorry, I'm a bit of an idiot in this ahah. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that's just using the Google Mobileads method. According to their documentation the call to initialize their SDK is:

`MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");`

Of course the ad unit ID in question will be your own.

Comment: Thank you! However, test ads are still not showing and for some reason, in the Chartboost and AdMob dashboards, they both say that for the ad unit, it has around 42 "bootups" but no impressions. Do I put the ad unit ID or app ID into that call?

Comment: DOESN'T MATTER I'VE SORTED IT! Turns out I just completely took AdMob out from trying to open the rewarded video ad and relied completely on the Chartboost methods to completely bypass AdMob. Therefore, I have initiaized the Chartboost SDK and not the AdMob SDK so only the Chartboost SDK is used. Thank you very much for your help so I could actually get a grip on what was going wrong ahah